# Finding generators of a kernel in a free resolution

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I am trying to find out the kernel (syzygy) in a free resolution.

Here $R = K[x,y,z]$ where $K$ is a field. I am trying to resolve the ideal $M=(x,y,z)$. I have the following resolution.

$ \phi_0 : R \rightarrow R/M$ by natural map. I get kernel as $(x,y,z)$. Now I need to map $R^3$ to $R$.

$\phi_1 : R^3 \rightarrow R$ by mapping the  3 generators of $R^3$ to $x, y$ and $z$ respectively. Now I get that

$\begin{bmatrix}
   0 &z &-y 
\\-z &0 &x
\\y &-x &0
\end{bmatrix}$ will be in the kernel. But I am not being able to show that the kernel is itself generated by this.

Answer (score 2):

So, $(f_1,f_2,f_3)\in\ker\phi_1$ iff $xf_1+yf_2+zf_3=0$. Then $xf_1\in(y,z)$, so $f_1\in(y,z)$. This shows that $f_1=yu_1-zv_1$. Do the same for $f_2,f_3$ and find what you want.

Comment: Will this argument work for this statement ? $xf_1\in(y,z) \implies  f_1\in(y,z)$. 
Agument : as $x$ is independent of $y$ and $z$ thus $f_1\in(y,z)$

Comment: @Abhi80 I'd say "because the ideal $(y,z)$ is prime and $x\notin(y,z)$".

Comment: what next? Please complete the resolution.